# Running file_put_contents through cmd not yielding same results as browser

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to run a simple script which grabs an xml file from a website and saves it 
in to a file, below is the function

```
/* update exchange rates */
public function getLatestExchangeRates(){       
   $xml = file_get_contents("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"); 
   file_put_contents("xml/exchange_rates.xml", $xml);
}

echo "Update Exchange Rates <br>\n";
$scraper->getLatestExchangeRates();
```

running this script in chrome works but when running it in cmd prompt using the following statement

`C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\bk\update_exchange_rates.php`

gives me the following error in the console..

`warning: file_put_contents(xml/exchange_rates.xml: failed to open stream: no such file or directory in C:....`

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: @xdazz but wouldn't that mean that I won't be able to run the file in a browser?

Comment: What I mean is change `"xml/exchange_rates.xml"` to absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is to use the

```
__DIR__
```

global contant to build the path to use.

```
$file = __DIR__ . "/xml/exchange_rates.xml"
```

will give you the directory of where the current script is running, which will solve running through apache and command line.